# Как сделать в PictureBox выделение какого-либо элемента?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть `PictureBox` с картинкой, на ней какие-то элементы (координаты элемента я задал) и при клике в эту область должно появляться сообщение типо "вы молодцы".
Ниже код, но он не работает, помогите его исправить:

```
public Form4()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    objects = new List<MapObject>();

    objects.Add(new MapObject()
    {
        Name = "Парусник",
        X = 193,
        Y = 35,
        Width = 32,
        Height = 40
    });
}

private void pictureBox4_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    int currentX = e.X;
    int currentY = e.Y;
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (currentX > (objects[i].X - objects[i].Width / 2) & currentX < (objects[i].X +
        objects[i].Width / 2)
        & currentY > (objects[i].Y - objects[i].Height / 2) & currentY <
        (objects[i].Y + objects[i].Height / 2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ghg");
        }
    }
}
```

а вот код из класса, созданного отдельно:

```
class MapObject
{
    public string Name;

    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public int Width;
    public int Height;
}
```

Comment: В последнее время часто вижу битовое `&` в условиях. Где, в каком руководстве люди их находят? Замените их на логические `&&` (да, именно два знака, а не один).

Comment: спасибо! помогло!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну положим для логических выражений операторы почти эквивалентны, с той разницей что для "логических" используются сокращенные вычисления выражений, а для "битовых" выражение вычисляется всегда полностью. Не знаю как для unity и mono, для классического .NET и .NET Core это работает именно так. Другой вопрос, что с битовыми можно прозевать ошибку в выражении, т.к. они могут выполняться и для чисел. Приведенное выражение, к слову, я проверил и с обоими типами операторов результат одинаковый, что я сделал не так?